# Count registers in columns sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a SQL table with below values

```
dozen1  dozen2  dozen3  dozen4  dozen5  dozen6
----------------------------------------------
10      27      40      46      49      58
 2      11      34      37      32      50
 3       4      29      36      45      55
14      32      33      36      44      52
20      11      36      38      47      53
 1       5      11      16      20      55
 2      18      31      42      51      52
 5      11      22      24      51      53
 1       3      11      17      34      45
```

I need count the quantity of results by number, sample :

```
Number 10 appears 1 time
Number  2 appears 2 times
```

Result:

```
Dozen   Times
--------------
10      1
 2      2
....
```

How do this in a SQL query?

Comment: What do you mean with "registers"? That's  not a term usually used with SQL (I only know it from assembler)

Comment: Your database design is a very bad choice. You should read up on normalization (with a properly normalized table, this would be as simple as `select dozen, count(*) from the-table group by dozen`)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count the number of occurrences of distinct numbers in all columns:

```
select dozen, count(*) as times
from my_table
cross join unnest(array[dozen1, dozen2, dozen3, dozen4, dozen5, dozen6]) u(dozen)
group by 1
order by 1;

 dozen | times 
-------+-------
     1 |     2
     2 |     2
     3 |     2
     4 |     1
     5 |     2  
etc...
```